# How can I see which Affinity Group my VM belongs to in Azure?

Tags: azure

Pardon the very simple (and stupid) question, but I have already checked every single option in Azure Management Portal and I can't find a VM's affinity group...  Where is this information shown?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ended up going the "easy way"... Quickly created a VM and set the affinity group... When you check the Management Portal, the column LOCATION will show "<AffinityGroup>(Region)" as in "Group1(Brazil South)".  If an Affinity Group is not set, it only shows "Region".

Answer (score 1):

Affinity groups have been deprecated and are no longer necessary.  Azure automatically keeps resources as close to one another as possible without placing them on the same hardware, which was the purpose of affinity groups.

Answer (score 0):

Affinity Groups are treated very similar to Regions, check where the VM has been deployed to.

Comment: The VM was deployed in Brazil South and there is one affinity group defined for the region... Does it mean it belongs there?

Comment: Nope, when you launch a new VM you can choose an existing affinity group or a standard region.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell is what you need to use, the command **Get-AzureAffinityGroup** will do the trick just nice.

here are more details about the command: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495248.aspx